# How do I process all viewable characters on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

An example of processing is to change all characters to uppercase. The webpage will be fully loaded before processing on the client side. I would like to process only the characters that are visible on the webpage. This means I will not touch HTML tags etc. that are not viewable. But I need to alter outputs from non-HTML sources, say JavaScript `document.write` or PHP scripts, that sends characters to output.

I am thinking of using JS HTML DOM. Is that a good mechanism? Looking for any other ideas.

Comment: For that specific example, CSS might be a good way to go. Applying the CSS rule `* { text-transform: uppercase !important; }` achieves the desired effect. For other transformations, CSS probably won't be an option.

Comment: Thanks but as you guessed correctly, I am looking for a generalized solution. For example, if I am doing this using JS, the generalized solution will simply call a function transform(). The function transform() converts the text to uppercase or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest case, where you only care about the HTML delivered to the client, almost any language will do. However, when you care about dynamically-generated content, you're right—the client-side DOM is the only way to go.

Essentially, here's what you've got to do:

1. Write a function to recursively walk nodes and transform the `nodeValue` of text and `CDATA` nodes.
2. Wire up a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) that examines `childList` changes in the subtrees of the document. When a record with `addedNodes` comes in, run your previous function for every node in the list.
3. Finally, run your transformation on the document to fix up anything that already exists.

Keep in mind that mutation observers are a relatively new addition to the DOM. If you need more support, you may want add a fallback to [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events), but even those don't have wide support, *and* they significantly degrade performance.